# IEnumerable erroring out on view with json object

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

Recently I figured out how to properly serialize a json string in a previous question but I am having a hard time displaying the result on the view now. I fixed my model and controller but the view seems to be the problem now. Here is the error I am receiving.

> Compilation Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'sWorkOrderNumber' and no extension method 'sWorkOrderNumber' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 4:  @foreach (var order in Model)
>
> Line 5:  {
>
> Line 6:      @Model.sWorkOrderNumber
>
> Line 7:  }

My controller code is as follows.

```
string url = @"URL of webservice here";

var returnValue = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);

        List<Order> shipments = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Order>>(returnValue);

        return View(shipments.ToList());
```

Here is my view.

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Order>

@foreach (var order in Model)
{
    @Model.sWorkOrderNumber
}
```

Here is the JSON that is getting returned.

```
[{"ShipmentTrackingNUmbers":[{"sTrackingNumber":"Redacted"}],"dtDateShipped":"5/12/2017 12:00:00 AM","dSPRatedWeight":"41.0000","nMBTotalBoxes":"1","sShipToAddressLine2":"Redacted","sShipToCountry":"U.S.A.","sShipToZip":"Redacted","sShipToState":"Redacted","sShipToCity":"Redacted","sShipToAddressLine1":"Redacted","sShipToName":"Redacted","sServiceLevel":"GND","sInvoiceNumber":"","dtInvoiceDate":"","mInvoiceAmount":"","dtDateReceived":"5/8/2017 3:16:25 PM","sStudioCategory2":"","sStudioCategory1":"","sOrderSource":"Redacted","sCustomerComments":"Redacted","sCustomerOrderName":"Redacted","sWorkOrderNumber":"Redacted","sCustomerNumber":"Redacted"},{"ShipmentTrackingNUmbers":[{"sTrackingNumber":"Redacted"}],"dtDateShipped":"5/10/2016 12:00:00 AM","dSPRatedWeight":"3.0000","nMBTotalBoxes":"1","sShipToAddressLine2":"","sShipToCountry":"U.S.A.","sShipToZip":"Redacted","sShipToState":"Redacted","sShipToCity":"Redacted","sShipToAddressLine1":"Redacted","sShipToName":"Redacted","sServiceLevel":"GND","sInvoiceNumber":"","dtInvoiceDate":"","mInvoiceAmount":"","dtDateReceived":"5/2/2016 7:18:41 AM","sStudioCategory2":"","sStudioCategory1":"","sOrderSource":"Redacted","sCustomerComments":"Redacted","sCustomerOrderName":"Redacted","sWorkOrderNumber":"Redacted","sCustomerNumber":"Redacted"}]
```

Order Model Code

```
public class ShipmentTrackingNumbers
{
    public string sTrackingNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public List<ShipmentTrackingNumbers> ShipmentTrackingNUmbers { get; set; }

    public string dtDateShipped
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string dSPRatedWeight
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string nMBTotalBoxes
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sShipToAddressLine2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sShipToCountry
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string ShipToZip
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sShipToState
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sShipToCity
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sShipToAddressLine1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sShipToName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sServiceLevel
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sInvoiceNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string dtInvoiceDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string mInvoiceAmount
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string dtDateReceived
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sStudioCategory2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sStudioCategory1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sOrderSource
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sCustomerComments
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sCustomerOrderName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sWorkOrderNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sCustomerNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.
Any guidance would be amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you seee in below formatted JSON, Its an Array of result so you need to loop through it to access any property.

```
   @foreach (var order in Model)
     {
       @Model.sWorkOrderNumber // (Wrong)
       @order.sWorkOrderNumber // (Right)
     }
```

and while looping user current object access properties.

```js
[
  {
    "ShipmentTrackingNUmbers": [
      {
        "sTrackingNumber": "Redacted"
      }
    ],
    "dtDateShipped": "5/12/2017 12:00:00 AM",
    "dSPRatedWeight": "41.0000",
    "nMBTotalBoxes": "1",
    "sShipToAddressLine2": "Redacted",
    "sShipToCountry": "U.S.A.",
    "sShipToZip": "Redacted",
    "sShipToState": "Redacted",
    "sShipToCity": "Redacted",
    "sShipToAddressLine1": "Redacted",
    "sShipToName": "Redacted",
    "sServiceLevel": "GND",
    "sInvoiceNumber": "",
    "dtInvoiceDate": "",
    "mInvoiceAmount": "",
    "dtDateReceived": "5/8/2017 3:16:25 PM",
    "sStudioCategory2": "",
    "sStudioCategory1": "",
    "sOrderSource": "Redacted",
    "sCustomerComments": "Redacted",
    "sCustomerOrderName": "Redacted",
    "sWorkOrderNumber": "Redacted",
    "sCustomerNumber": "Redacted"
  },
  {
    "ShipmentTrackingNUmbers": [
      {
        "sTrackingNumber": "Redacted"
      }
    ],
    "dtDateShipped": "5/10/2016 12:00:00 AM",
    "dSPRatedWeight": "3.0000",
    "nMBTotalBoxes": "1",
    "sShipToAddressLine2": "",
    "sShipToCountry": "U.S.A.",
    "sShipToZip": "Redacted",
    "sShipToState": "Redacted",
    "sShipToCity": "Redacted",
    "sShipToAddressLine1": "Redacted",
    "sShipToName": "Redacted",
    "sServiceLevel": "GND",
    "sInvoiceNumber": "",
    "dtInvoiceDate": "",
    "mInvoiceAmount": "",
    "dtDateReceived": "5/2/2016 7:18:41 AM",
    "sStudioCategory2": "",
    "sStudioCategory1": "",
    "sOrderSource": "Redacted",
    "sCustomerComments": "Redacted",
    "sCustomerOrderName": "Redacted",
    "sWorkOrderNumber": "Redacted",
    "sCustomerNumber": "Redacted"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model is of type `IEnumerable<Project.Models.Order>` which is collection and you are already iterating on your collection using `foreach`.

So, instead of referring to `@Model` you need to use the loop variable to access each order value in the collection by using `order` variable:

```
@foreach (var order in Model)
{
    @order.sWorkOrderNumber
}
```

You have multiple orders objects coming via `IEnumerable<T>` and you need to access each one via foreach like you are doing but inside loop body you are using wrong variable.

Hope it helps.